# How can I make an item in an array come before another after sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I was given a array to sort but after sorting the array a particular element should come before another.

`var array = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 1,3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];`

the output should be  `// 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,Jack,Queen,King`

In which Queen would come before King
My solution:

````
var array = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 1,3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];

array.sort()

console.log(array); ```

But my output is:
```[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen'] ```
````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The letter Q is after letter K in the alphabet
So sorting works properly(by letters in alphabetical order) if you want it to sort other way you should create custom sort.

Look into compare section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
and also I would suggest going with different approach of having the map array with the "cards" because I think thats what you wanna sort ordered correctly and just compare indices from that array or key value map. Example with custom compare function and card values map.

```js
const cardValueMap = {
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 8,
  9: 9,
  10: 10,
  Jack: 11,
  Queen: 12,
  King: 13,
  Ace: 14,
}

const array = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]

const compareCards = (a, b) => {
  if (cardValueMap[a] < cardValueMap[b]) {
    return -1
  }
  if (cardValueMap[a] > cardValueMap[b]) {
    return 1
  }
  return 0
}

array.sort(compareCards)
console.log(array)
```

Could be upgraded by checking `typeof a`/ `typeof b` to not have to include numbers in map.

Note that I also removed "1" from your array since there is no card with number 1.

Comment: Thank you for response. But can I create a custom sort

Comment: I've already shown an example in the response @JafarLi-hammed

Answer (score 0):

Map `Jack`, `Queen` and `King` to numbers, sort the integer array and then reverse map numbers for `Jack`, `Queen` and `King`.

```js
var array = ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const ans = array
  .map(x => {
    if (x === 'Jack') return 10;
    else if (x === 'Queen') return 11;
    else if (x === 'King') return 12;
    return x;
  })
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .map(x => {
    if (x === 10) return 'Jack';
    else if (x === 11) return 'Queen';
    else if (x === 12) return 'King';
    return x;
  });

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: Well you could to this translation to card "values" in your sort in comparing function and it would be iterating over the array only once instead of three times.